# Configure parent/root project for child project in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to set parent project of a child gradle project.

In my case, all parent and child project lies on same level in the file hierarchy. For example

- code

  - /parent project

    - build.gradle
  - /child project1

    - build.gradle
  - /child project2

    - build.gradle

Here porject 1 depends on project2, so i am referring them as

```
compile project(':../project2')
```

also in my settings.gradle file , i have

```
include '../child_project1'
include '../child_project1'
```

with this i am able to run tasks from parent project folder but individual tasks are not running from child projects.

Comment: Not sure, but `includeFlat` may be what you need: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat(java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but you can do this by specifying the child project like this in your `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':A'
project(':A').projectDir = new File('../A')
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out section 20.3.2.2. of the [Gradle doc on Multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:multi_project_builds). One can use `includeFlat` in the `settings.gradle` file.